# How do you load an XML file into a string with python on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, typeerror

I'm using the latest GAE default python environment. Both of these give expected results:

```
isTrue = os.path.exists(path)
numberGreaterThanZero = os.path.getsize(path)
```

But this:

```
myStrLen = len(open(path))
```

Gives this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'FakeFile' has no len()
```

There are no results for that error in Google. Not being able to open files is a real bummer. What am I doing wrong? Why does Python/GAE think my file is fake?

Comment: GAE provides restricted file access. Have you tried just reading the file?

Comment: I have tried reading the file like this: `strToRead = open(path)`. `strToRead` ends up empty and operations on that string result in the FakeFile error. I can render a template from a file in the same directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `open` function returns an open file, not a string. Open files have no `len`.

You need to actually read the string from the file,  for example with the [`read`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) method.

```
contents = open(path).read()
myStrLen = len(contents)
```

If you don't need the contents, you can also get the file size with [`os.stat`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat).

```
myStrLen = os.stat('/tmp/x.py').st_size
```

`FakeFile` is just GAE's sandboxed implementation of `file`.

Comment: You guys on here are awesome. I was so fixated on that FakeFile error that I missed the read method.